# JSF / Primefaces Validation depending which button is pressed

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces

I have a form with a few inputs and some buttons. According the button which is pressed the required fields should change.

Lets say I have three inputs A, B and C and two Buttons X, Y.
A is never validated.
B is only validated when button X is pressed.
C is only validated when button Y is pressed.

I already have a custom validate method.